# Calculate into new Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A  dataframe columns looks like this:

```
VALUE  
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 ...
 40
```

i want to produce two new columns for eah value like this:

```
    df['VALUE1'] = math.cos(df['VALUE'] * 2 * math.pi / 48)
    df['VALUE2'] = math.sin(df['VALUE'] * 2 * math.pi / 48)
```

but my Script crashes with no errors given...

The result should be something like this:

```
VALUE  VALUE1    VALUE2
 1      ...        ...
 2      ...        ...
 3
 4
 5
 ...
 40    ...         ...
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: `math.cos` functions dont take series/dataframes, it needs floats, you could use `np.cos` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.sin` and `math.cos` don't accept series. Use `numpy`, vector methods are fast.

```
In [511]: df = pd.DataFrame({'VALUE': range(1, 41)})

In [512]: df['VALUE1'] = np.cos(df['VALUE'] * 2 * np.pi /48)

In [513]: df['VALUE2'] = np.sin(df['VALUE'] * 2 * np.pi /48)

In [514]: df.head()
Out[514]:
   VALUE    VALUE1    VALUE2
0      1  0.991445  0.130526
1      2  0.965926  0.258819
2      3  0.923880  0.382683
3      4  0.866025  0.500000
4      5  0.793353  0.608761
```

You could use `apply`, but they tend to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried apply?

```
df['VALUE1'] = df['VALUE'].apply(lambda x: math.cos(x * 2 * math.pi / 48))
df['VALUE2'] = df['VALUE'].apply(lambda x: math.sin(x * 2 * math.pi / 48))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Numpy functions as they can work with vectors (columns) instead of `math`

```
In [23]: df = df.assign(VALUE1=np.cos(df['VALUE'] * 2 * np.pi / 48),
                        VALUE2=np.sin(df['VALUE'] * 2 * np.pi / 48))

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   VALUE    VALUE1    VALUE2
0      1  0.991445  0.130526
1      2  0.965926  0.258819
2      3  0.923880  0.382683
3      4  0.866025  0.500000
4      5  0.793353  0.608761
5     40  0.500000 -0.866025
```